# Working UDP Receive program suddenly fails with: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#

For months and months my UDP Receive app has worked flawlessly. It receives a message on a specified port and sends out another message to a .php application that updates a database. It no longer can send the message to the web program.

It was working fine up until today.

The command that fails is:

```
var stream = client.OpenRead(url);
```

Was there a .NET or Windows 10 upgrade that would cause this to fail?
I checked the url parameter and the web program is working just fine.

How do I fix this?

Comment: _The command that fails is_ - this is a bit lacking in detail. How does it 'fail'? Does it send the command? Has the php app changed? Is there an error? Does the php app receive the command? If so, what does it do with it? Does it work with other URLs?

Comment: There had been no changes to either the UDP app or the PHP app. It fails with the message in the heading: "The underlying connection was closed..." As soon as it hits the line: var stream = ... The PHP app does not receive the message.

Comment: Has the server that hosts the UDP or the PHP app been updated?

Comment: I have more information now. I copied the PHP program to my GODADDY server where it works perfectly. It still fails on the IONOS server. The IONOS program does work from my browser but not from my UDP Receive program. Could IONOS have turned on some sort of filter that only allows PHP access via a browser and not a program?

Comment: I should add one other thing. At IONOS, the PHP program URL was HTTPS whereas Godaddy is HTTP. If that makes a difference?

Comment: _Could IONOS have turned on some sort of filter that only allows PHP access via a browser and not a program?_ you could try setting a User Agent string on the client?